# How do I Notify the Client when a Payment Systems sends a Request to my API callback URL?

Tags: node.js, api, express, vue.js, stripe-payments

I'm currently building a website with Vue.JS as my static frontend and writing a separate backend API hosted in the cloud using Node and Express.

Currently, I want to integrate payments with a payment provider called [Swish](https://assets.ctfassets.net/zrqoyh8r449h/66tl0gSWnecV4uak9kdgJO/a5e3fe50277884198a5c62fbadca773d/Merchant_Integration_Guide.pdf). The way this API works is that a payment request is issued from the client with a Callback URL that Swish calls when the payment Errors or is Paid. This URL will be a post request to my API. I want to know how the "Create Payment Request" can asynchronously wait for the post request to be issued by my payment provider so that it returns when Swish (payment provider) is done processing the payment and I can then update the status of the payment in Vue to the user.

I haven't managed to solve this without polling yet. A simple solution would be to have the Post request that Swish visits update some state in my SQL database and have the "Create Payment Request" wake up every 10 seconds or so to check if the database has been changed. **Is there a way to do this without polling? Could I somehow emit some event to wake up a sleeping Express endpoint from another Express endpoint? Or could I pass to the callback URL some webhook or something so that the Swish callback can directly notify my Vue frontend when it's called?**

For timescales, it takes a maximum of 3 minutes for Swish to call the callback URL.

Comment: I dont believe there are other solutions available when youre using a db like MySQL. You'd have to poll for changes. I know that there are solutions for other database solutions (like Google Firebase) which work using sockets.

Comment: Would it be stupid to have the callback insert into the SQL database and have the polling do a SELECT query? If I get many requests wouldn't that lock my database quite a lot? What about something like socket.io? Could that be used to emit an event to another endpoint from within the callback?

Comment: Read queries do not have to bother with locks, unless you're doing transactions which is another story. Socket.io can probably be used, which means your Node server does the polling, and then the connection to the frontend takes place using the socket. Not sure if it is easy to setup though.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) should work for your problem. As you already said you should persist the state of the payment in your database. When the Swish app calls your callback url you send an websocket request with the new state and needed information. The state is needed when the websocket connection is recreated due errors in the communication.

Some links which may be usefull:

- [websockets/ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws)
- [nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket](https://github.com/nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket)
- [sockjs/sockjs-client](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)
- [stomp-js/stompjs](https://github.com/stomp-js/stompjs)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Who exactly do I sent the Websocket request to? Can I have the callback URL handler send a request to the "Create request" to wake it up and finish?

Comment: And do I need to use a websocket on the frontend? I would like to handle it through the backend and not have to change my frontend too much

Comment: Yes, you need an integration in the frontend. The websockets are just a easy way to push a message form your backend to your frontend instead of polling. How you process the swish stuff is independent from the websockets.